# Can I set dynamic class name in React Jss with destructing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss, css-in-js

I am using something like this `` <span className={`${status_icon}  ${classes[`${status}`]}`} /> `` but I want to destructor the object and use it. Is there any way to do it ?

Currently I have

```js
const classes = useStyles();  
const { status_icon } = classes;
```

I want to use it like this

```js
const {status_icon, learning_in_progress, not_started} = useStyles();
```

**Source code - [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/objective-leftpad-rr1gv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**

```js
import React from "react";
import { createUseStyles } from "react-jss";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>
        <LearnGridStatus status="not_started" />
        Not Started
      </h3>

      <h3>
        <LearnGridStatus status="learning_in_progress" />
        In Progress
      </h3>
    </>
  );
}

function LearnGridStatus({ status }) {
  const styles = {
    status_icon: {
      display: "inline-block",
      marginRight: "8px",
      width: "15px",
      height: "15px",
      verticalAlign: "middle",
      borderRadius: "50%"
    },
    not_started: {
      background: "#6a7887"
    },
    learning_in_progress: {
      background: "#3dc3ff"
    }
  };

  const useStyles = createUseStyles(styles);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { status_icon } = classes;

  return (
    <span className={`${status_icon}  ${classes[`${status}`]}`} />
  );
}
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring):

```
const styles = {
  status_icon: {
    display: "inline-block",
    marginRight: "8px",
    width: "15px",
    height: "15px",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
    borderRadius: "50%"
  },
  not_started: {
    background: "#6a7883"
  },
  learning_in_progress: {
    background: "#3dc3ff"
  }
};

const useStyles = createUseStyles(styles);

function LearnGridStatus({ status }) {
  const { status_icon, [status]: currentStatus } = useStyles();

  return <span className={`${status_icon}  ${currentStatus}`} />;
}
```

Working example:

[image: Edit dynamic jss]